# Java User Input and Difference between readInt and nextInt?

Tags: java, difference

What is wrong with this?

```
import java.io.*;

class TUI{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter the two numbers:");
        int n1=readInt("Enter n1:");
        int n2=readInt("Enter n2:");
        int total=n1+n2;
        System.out.println("Total is =" + total+".");
    }
}
```

Getting these errors

```
Day2.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    int n1=readInt("Enter n1:");
           ^
  symbol:   method readInt(String)
  location: class TUI
Day2.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
    int n2=readInt("Enter n2:");
           ^
  symbol:   method readInt(String)
  location: class TUI
```

PS- Also What is the difference between `readInt` and `nextInt` ?
Can I use `nextInt` here

Comment: You don't have a readInt method. No, you can't use nextInt there, because you also don't have a nextInt method. You'll need an instance of Scanner to use them.

Comment: you are not defined a method called `readInt()`.

Comment: Please align your code, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like a scanner to read-in values from console.
The code should look like that:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class TUI {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the two numbers:");
        System.out.println("Enter n1:");
        int n1 = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter n2:");
        int n2 = scanner.nextInt();
        int total = n1 + n2;
        System.out.println("Total is =" + total + ".");
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. . I am new to java and want to go for Android Development later. CAn you please tell me which book/tutorial should I follow and what is the difference between readInt and nextInt?

Comment: I do not know the implementation of readInt, but nextInt waits for input from console. There are many tutorials at the web after googling I have found this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

Answer (score 0):

readInt is used with datainputstream class.
nextInt with scanner class and you need to create a scanner object inorder to get input values.
i.e

```
java.util.Scanner obj=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
      int x=obj.nextInt();
```

Objective of both is the same to read integer values.