# readInt and readLine to make basic adding machine in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a simple adding machine.

```
public class AddingMachine {   // Save as 'AddingMachine.java"
   public static void main(String[] args) {  
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Adding Machine.");
    System.out.println();

    String name = readLine("What is your name? ");
    int num1 = readInt("What is the first number? ");
    int num2 = readInt("What is the second number? ");
    System.out.println();

    int sum = num1 + num2;
    System.out.print(name);
    System.out.print(", the sum is: ");
    System.out.print(sum);
    }
}
```

The error message reports "cannot find symbol" `readInt` or `readString` but I have found the methods on the Oracle website:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html

There may be some other methods that can solve this problem, but I think the `read` methods make for a very simple input/output example.

Comment: you have not defined readLine function

Comment: You have to provide an instance of an object that has the methods `readInt()` and `readString()`. Similar methods are already present in the class [`java.util.Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java User Input and Difference between readInt and nextInt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494712/java-user-input-and-difference-between-readint-and-nextint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution,

readInt and readLine are the methods from scanner class.

```
public class AddingMachine {   // Save as 'AddingMachine.java"
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Adding Machine.");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("What is the first number?");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is the second number?");
        int num2 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        int sum = num1 + num2;
        System.out.print(sum);
        System.out.print(", the sum is: ");
        System.out.print(sum);
  }
}
```

Comment: So to use readInt, I would need to import `java.util.Scanner;`?  or use dot notation: `scanner.readInt`

Comment: u need to import java.util.scanner and then create scanner object as i did (refer sc object)

Comment: @SparkletheUnicorn Please accept the answer if it solves your problem